# Why is the referenced int being cast to a void pointer?

Tags: c++, sockets

```
void Link::keepalive(bool enable){
    int opt = enable? 1 : 0;
    ::setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&opt, sizeof(opt));
}
```

I keep seeing code like the following in some of the more low-level c functions especially when it pertains to sockets and networking operations.

I'm coming from a python background, and I've certain looked around for good explanations as to what `(void *)&opt` is doing, but have yet to 
find a good explaination.

I get that a reference is merely a pointer with restrictions.

Comment: The `(void *)` is called a `cast`ing which essentially indicates that the pointer (address of `opt` variable) should be considered as a pointer to a `void` data type. In most of the cases, in `C`, this is not required or redundant.

Comment: In C++ you should use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `&opt` is not a reference, and the cast is not needed in C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

The signature for `setsockopt`

```
int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name,
   const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len);
```

Its second last argument should be of type `void *`. To make `&opt` of type `void *` it is catsted to that type.

Also note that `&opt` is the address of `opt` object. Its not reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed quite a mess which exists in the first place because setsockopt() is supporting tons of different options (SO_KEEPALIVE is just one of them).

- To enable passing *any* parameter (including future extensions), they've said that setsockopt() will accept a pointer to the parameter, where parameter type is *any pointer* (and is implicitly defined by option_name parameter, in this case SO_KEEPALIVE).

  - this ensures that setsockopt() prototype remains the same for all the future values of SO_* options
- in C, "any pointer" is written as "void*"
- &opt is "pointer to opt" (or "address of opt")
- as "opt" has type int, "&opt" has type int*, so to convert it to void*, there is an "explicit cast" (void*)&opt in your code

  - however, in most cases it is not necessary, as cast to void* is implicit, so simple "&opt" should do
- this kind of trickery, while common in C APIs, is generally discouraged in C++, so don't take it as an example of "how to write C++ programs"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MSDN's documentation for the [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx) function, in particular the **Remarks** section:

> There are two types of socket options: Boolean options that enable or disable a feature or behavior, and options that require an integer value or structure. To enable a Boolean option, the optval parameter points to a nonzero integer. To disable the option optval points to an integer equal to zero. The optlen parameter should be equal to sizeof(int) for Boolean options. **For other options, optval points to an integer or structure that contains the desired value for the option, and optlen is the length of the integer or structure.**

It is a common practice in C APIs to pass function arguments that can be of different type/length as the most general pointer type `(void *)` pointing on their address in memory.

`&opt` returns pointer/address to `opt` of type `(int *)` in your case, so it needs to be cast to `(void *)`. Also when writing for C++, prefer using [explicit type conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Comment: Microsoft is not the only (and by far not the first) system which implements Berkeley Sockets in general, and setsockopt() in particular, so naming MSDN an "official documentation" is a very long shot.